# How do you check which thread is executing code in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, assert

I have a multi-threaded Java program with a bunch of rules around threading: For example,  code in class A should only be called from the UI thread;   3 methods in class B must be called only from the network thread, etc.

Any suggestions on how to do assertions or other code checks that these rules are being followed?   I'd like to do the equivalent of testing for "invariants" to prevent coding errors on thread usage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to adamfisk's excellent suggestion, there is also a convenience method for specifically testing whether the current thread is the EDT thread:

```
EventQueue.isDispatchThread()
```

Comment: +1 - when writing Swing, the UI/not-UI question is usually the only one that's important.

Comment: thanks, I'm not using swing but I suppose many people reading this will be.

Answer (score 22):

Thread.currentThread().getName()

Comment: +1 Care to round out your answer with rd01's answer for the swing case?

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
assert Thread.currentThread() == expectedThread;
```

The problem with using the name is that any number of threads can use that name e.g. if you are particularly paranoid you might worry about code like this.

```
Thread.t = Thread.currentThread();
String name = t.getName();
t.setName("UI thread");
callUIThreadOnlyMethod();
t.setName(name);
```

Comment: Are there scenarios besides a malicious coder where this kind of aliasing would occur?

Comment: Poor thread naming standards and copy-paste errors.  Most programs are not written to ensure thread names are unique and you see duplicate names often.

Answer (score 3):

Consider inverting the question.  Consider prevention instead of enforcement.

If class Mangalor can only be run in a UI thread, limit the visibility of the Mangalor class to UI classes.
If methods talk() and listen() of class CanOnString must only be run in a networking thread, limit the visibility of those methods to classes that you run in your networking thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this in my code in class A:

```
if(!"UI thread".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())){
    throw new IllegalStateException("wrong thread running this class, thread name:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check thread name using logging e.g. log4j or logback, just set a pattern including `%thread` like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```